# "got multiple values for keyword argument" when using *args, **kwargs in a python function

Tags: python, python-2.7, keyword-argument

When passing a named parameter `request` through `**kwargs`, I get an error-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testKwargs.py", line 9, in <module>
    load_strategy(request="myReq", backend="myBackend", redirect_uri=None, *args, **kwargs)
  File "testKwargs.py", line 5, in load_strategy
    get_strategy("backends", "strategy", "storage", *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: get_strategy() got multiple values for keyword argument 'request'
```

The code in `testKwargs.py` is below-

```
def get_strategy(backends, strategy, storage, request=None, backend=None, *args, **kwargs):
    print request

def load_strategy(*args, **kwargs):
    get_strategy("backends", "strategy", "storage", *args, **kwargs)

args = ([],)
kwargs = {"acess_token":"myAccToken", "id":"myId"}
load_strategy(request="myReq", backend="myBackend", redirect_uri=None, *args, **kwargs)
```

I was expecting that there would be one key-value pair for the key `request` in the `**kwargs` of `load_strategy` which was passed on to the `request` parameter in `get_stragegy`, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

I am trying to figure out what I am missing here.

Comment: If you mean `get_strategy()` not being a method of a class, then yes, I am certain that that is not the case. Infact the small code snippet in the question is enough to repro the problem.

Comment: Yes, I saw that you were indeed providing a full SSCCE, then saw the mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing in an **extra** positional argument:

```
args = ([],)
```

There is one value in that tuple, a list object. It is applied after the other three arguments passed to `get_strategy()`, so to `request`. Python sees you calling:

```
get_strategy("backends", "strategy", "storage", [],
             request="myReq", backend="myBackend", redirect_uri=None, 
             acess_token="myAccToken", id="myId")
```

and the 4 positional arguments are applied against the `backends`, `strategy`, `storage` and `request` parameters respectively.

If you meant to pass in 3 positional arguments,  then specify `args` as an empty tuple:

```
args = ()
```

and things work just fine:

```
>>> def get_strategy(backends, strategy, storage, request=None, backend=None, *args, **kwargs):
...     print request
... 
>>> def load_strategy(*args, **kwargs):
...     get_strategy("backends", "strategy", "storage", *args, **kwargs)
... 
>>> args = ()
>>> kwargs = {"acess_token":"myAccToken", "id":"myId"}
>>> load_strategy(request="myReq", backend="myBackend", redirect_uri=None, *args, **kwargs)
myReq
```