# TypeError: got multiple values for argument when passing in *args

Tags: python, parameters, arguments, parameter-passing

Everytime I try to assign a default argument a value, when also using *args, it raises the error: TypeError: "got multiple values for argument".

```
def test(a,b, c=3, *args):
    pass

args = [1,2,3]
test(1,2,c=3, *args)
```

.

```
TypeError: test() got multiple values for argument 'c'
```

At first I thought I found the answer here:
[TypeError: got multiple values for argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21764770/typeerror-got-multiple-values-for-argument)
But it turns out that the first argument in that qusetion was being explictly overwritten, so in my own example this would be the same thing as saying test(1,2, a=3, *args) where a would be given values 1 and 3. However here that is not the case.

This question might be a possible duplicate of this one ["got multiple values for keyword argument" when using *args, **kwargs in a python function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20600870/got-multiple-values-for-keyword-argument-when-using-args-kwargs-in-a-pytho) but honestly, there are a lot more details in that question that is beyond the scope of what am asking for and I really can't follow it through. So if this is a duplicate, then it abstracts everything away from the other question down to the actual problem itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to swap it so the `c=3` is last because python requires optional arguments to be at the end. The code functions when it is done like this:

```
def test(a,b, *args, c=3):
    pass

args = [1,2,3]
test(1,2, *args, c=3)
```

Comment: Thanks man, this was honestly driving me mad, much appreciated :)

Comment: @JimJam happy to help

Comment: Hey, actually it turns out that that's not the way it's meant to be done, it's... complicated... I wish I could post my answer here but the questions been closed so i'll have to type it in here. But basically, if you have test(a,b *args, c=3), it means everything after the arg has to be kwonly args, so you lose the ability to have both default arguments and default only arguments.

Comment: I know that this question didn't concern kwonly args but it turns out to be a natural consequence of doing it the way you did it. The only way you could have both default and kwonly args is to do test(a,b, c=3, *args, d,e). However, in the function call you can't do something like 'c=[value'], so you just have to put in the value that you'd want. But by doing that, you can then have default args and kwonly args.

Comment: I am not following you, can you show an example of what you can and can't do

Comment: Yeah, I'd love to, but I can't post an answer. It's interesting though because it turns out there's only one way of setting things up whereby you can have positional, default, and kwonly args. That's not me saying "my way is the only way", it seems like it's that way by design.

Comment: that isn't a problem though, you can just do it explicitly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205880/discussion-between-jim-jam-and-hippolippo).

Answer (score 3):

You're specifying a keyword argument and *after* a list of positional arguments, which is why you're getting the error. Specify first all positional arguments and then keyword arguments:

```
def test(a,b, *args, c=3):
    print(args)
```

---

```
test(1,2,c=3, *args)
# (1, 2, 3)
```